# Does Java support creating a type with LESS properties than a parent type?

Tags: java

When `class A` **extends** `class B`, `A` can have more properties than `B`.

What about `class A` **extracted from** `class B`? Then `class A` can only has a subset of properties of `class B`.

I think this will be useful in some cases.

Comment: Inheritance works in 2 ways i.e Generalization vs Specialization. If many similar existing objects are combined to form a superclass to do the job of its subclass', then it is known as Generalization while if some new subclasses are created from an existing superclass to do specific job of the superclass, then it is known as specialization.

What you are talking about is Generalization i.e. A is extracted from Class B. This could be achieved with the help of abstract class or Interface

Comment: Post some practical stuff that represents what you mean and what do you mean "`class A` extracted from `class B`"? What is the meaning of **"extracted"**? Never heard about such a term in Java.

Comment: No. It does not. Interfaces can help separate the contract from the class hierarchy. In other cases, imagine an Immutable Collection, the methods which would cause mutation throw an Exception -- so while the *type information* does not convey this information, the semantics are that the methods that do not apply will die horribly. (It would perhaps be better to have corresponding Immutable/Mutable interfaces, but this is not the case...)

Answer (score 1):

One possible interpretation of your description is the concept of [polymorphism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polymorphism_in_object-oriented_programming) (see code). However in terms of *deriving* a class from B with lesser capabilities, no this isn't a language feature in java.

```
public class A {
    public int x = 5;
}

public class B extends A {
    public int y = 10;
}

...

B b = new B(); // Behaves like a B object should
System.out.println(b.y); // works
A a = (A)b; // Cast it to a parent class
System.out.println(a.y); // fails
```

Comment: +1 for answering the question. It is interesting note that some languages like Eiffel allow this sort of construct, though, then again, Eiffel has a different idea of how to implement polymorphism :)